# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln {\sqrt[n]{1+ \frac{x}{n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to know for which values of $x$ this series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln {\sqrt[n]{1+ \frac{x}{n}}}$$ converges.

This series is defined for:

$\sqrt[n]{1+ \frac{x}{n}}>0 \Rightarrow 1+ \frac{x}{n}>0 \Rightarrow \frac{x}{n}>-1 \Rightarrow x>-n \Rightarrow x>-1$ .

So the series is defined for $x>-1$

$a_n=\ln {\sqrt[n]{1+ \frac{x}{n}}} = \frac{\ln (1+ \frac{x}{n})}{n} \sim 0$
because the logarithmic function grows slower than any power of n.

Applying the root criterion we have:

$\sqrt[n]{|\frac{\ln (1+ \frac{x}{n})}{n}|}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{|\ln (1+ \frac{x}{n})|}{n}} \sim \sqrt[n]{|\ln (1+ \frac{x}{n})|} \sim \sqrt[n]{|\frac{x}{n}|} \sim \sqrt[n]{|x|}<1$ for $|x|<1$

So the given series converges for $-1<x<+1$

In my book the suggested result is $x>-1$ but I don't know why

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: Your last approx nth root for $|\frac{x}{n}|$ to $|x|$ is not needed.  As n increases $|\frac{x}{n}|$  shrinks $\lt 1$.

Comment: You cannot use the root criterion as $\sqrt[n]{\lvert x\rvert} \to 1$ for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: You can use comparison test with the fact that $\log(1+x) < x$ for positive $x$. The ratio and root tests should be inconclusive I think. Those only work for series that go to zero geometrically.

Comment: @mrtaurho The title did not match the question, as they were not asking us to evaluate the series ;)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I misread the first sentence as I realized now; thank you for the save :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\sqrt[n]{|x|}=x^{1/n}\to x^0=1$$

so that the root criterion is inconclusive. One can more simply use the limit comparison test to notice essentially what you already had though:

$$\frac1n\ln\left(1+\frac xn\right)\sim\frac x{n^2}$$

and hence it converges for all $x>-1$ since $\sum1/n^2$ converges.

Comment: ahh ok, I was a bit confused, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Note that for $x\ge 0$, $n\ge 1$

$$\begin{align}
0\le \log\left(\sqrt[n]{1+\frac xn}\right)\le \frac{x}{n^2}
\end{align}$$

What happens for $-1<x< 0$?  Can you finish now?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there with the equivalent, but you never want to write $\sim 0$, which is imprecise at best, wrong at worst. The equivalent is supposed to give you how fast the convergence is. Moreover, the $\ln$ in the expression does not *grow*, so the sequence $(a_n)$ tends to zero because it is of the type $0/\infty$.

Now, getting back to this, you have $\ln(1+u) \sim u$ as $u \to 0$, and therefore
$$
a_n = \ln \sqrt[n]{1 + \frac{x}{n}} = \frac1n \ln \left ( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right ) \sim \frac1n \frac{x}{n} = \frac{x}{n^2},
$$
so $|a_n| \sim |x|/n^2$. We know that the series $\sum |x|/n^2$ converges, so $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely.

It is true that technically, the expression is only valid for $n$ large enough, but you typically disregard this when you deal with series.

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\lim_{n \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln \sqrt[n]{1+\frac{k}{n}}=\lim_{n \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln (1+\frac{k}{n})= \int_{0}^{1}\ln(1+\frac{k}{n}) dx$$
$$S=(1+x)\ln(1+x)-(1+x)|_{0}^{1}=\ln 2-2+1= 2\ln 2-1$$